# How can I get the current operating system name in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In Ruby, I would use the `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant to determine what operating system (Mac, Windows, Linux etc) my program is running on.  Does Elixir have a way to get this information?

I'm currently attempting to re-create a Ruby program I wrote in Elixir, and I have a method that will make an OS-dependent system call to open a document.  The method looks something like:

```
def self.open_document(filename)
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when %r(darwin)
    system('open', filename)
  when %r(linux)
    system('xdg-open', filename)
  when %r(windows)
    system('cmd', '/c', "\"start #{filename}\"")
  else
    puts "Don't know how to open file"
  end
end
```

I know I can run the Ruby [`Kernel.system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) commands using Elixir's [`System.cmd/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cmd/3), but I'm not sure how to get the `RUBY_PLATFORM` value equivalent to make the switch on in the `case` statement, or whether I can actually get that information.  Is this possible?

#### Update

As per [Lol4t0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774651/lol4t0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461414/567863) and for further reference:

```
iex> :os.type
{:unix, :darwin}
iex> System.cmd("uname", ["-s"])
{"Darwin\n", 0}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call Erlang [`os:type`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#type-0) to get platform name info:

> ```
> type() -> {Osfamily, Osname}
> ```
>
> Types:
>
> ```
> Osfamily = unix | win32
> Osname = atom()
> ```
>
> Returns the Osfamily and, in some cases, Osname of the current
>   operating system.
>
> On Unix, Osname will have same value as `uname -s` returns, but in
>   lower case. For example, on Solaris 1 and 2, it will be sunos.
>
> In Windows, Osname will be either `nt` (on Windows NT), or `windows`
>   (on Windows 95).

In Elixir you probably have to call

```
:os.type()
```

to refer to that function with `Osfamily` being `:unix` or `:win32`.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks very much!